# Data cache in Shared Preference

Tags: android, caching, sharedpreferences

I have 2 processes in my application. From one process i save data in to `SharedPreferences`.
From second process - retrieve. When i retrieve data, i receive `SharedPreferences` with old data(i check xml file and see, that currently data in file and data that was received are different). It looks like this data was cached. I changed saving methods (commit/apply) but no result.
PS: just for example http://pastebin.com/Zx2ffvSg

```
//saving
{ ...
 SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putString(MY_NAME, "Sai");
    prefsEditor.putString(MY_WALLPAPER, "f664.PNG");
    prefsEditor.commit();
... }

//retrieving
// when i call getData() I put "this" as argument.
public void getData(Context context){
SharedPreferences myPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
...}
```

Comment: we'd have to see some code to see where the error is

Comment: i think that it is not suitable in this situation. I describe simple work with SharedPreference. Maybe there are any "pitfalls" in my situation?

Comment: Make sure the key in the key-value pair is the same.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The solution is add to neccesary flags Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS flag when open shared preference  (Available in API Level 11 and up)