# Shared preferences are not persistent

Tags: java, android

I use Shared preferences. I save String and then call it back from another activity. Its all work good.  But if I kill process of my app, or if I reboot device,  shared preferences don't work. It seems like shared preferences cleared wile reboot or killing process. I read a lot of forums, but the most recent answer is "don't forgot to use editor.commit()".
I use SONY mobile, I try to install it on Samsung tab, but the result is the same.

i created new simplest app but the result is the same.

MainActivity

```
package com.example.nes.test;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements             View.OnClickListener {
Button btnext,SavePref;
public static SharedPreferences sPref;
String data;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnext);
    btnext.setOnClickListener(this);
    SavePref = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SavePref);
    SavePref.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnext:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);break;
        case R.id.SavePref:
            sPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
            ed.putString(data,"aasdjf");
            ed.commit();break;

    }
}
}
```

Mainactivity2

```
package com.example.nes.test;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
SharedPreferences sPref;
String data;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    sPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());;
    String database = sPref.getString(data, "");
    Toast.makeText(this, database, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


}
```

manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main2" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Could you include the error message you get back, if you get one back?  Also, since we don't know what these objects are, could you also be sure to include some more context?  Are you programming in Android?

Comment: You may have the same problem as I had some time ago; a threading issue, solved by adding the MODE_MULTI_PROCESS flag: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8742735/1127492

Comment: I tryed this to. i tryed all possible modes

Comment: Android studio tells me that the line ArrayList<String> DB = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(database.split(","))); gives an error, but thats becoose String is NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can's see where `data` String is being instantiated. You're passing it as an argument in both classes, I guess in order to retrieve (`Mainactivity2`) what you saved first (`MainActivity`); but since the load is being done in `onCreate()` method, I really can't see where you're setting `data` variable. So, instead of writing:

```
sPref.getString(data, "");
```

Please just test with a wired key, like this:

```
//saving, (`MainActivity`)
ed.putString("DATA_KEY","aasdjf");

//loading, (`Mainactivity2`)
sPref.getString("DATA_KEY", "");
```

On both savin and retrieving, and see if something changes

Comment: ITS ALIVE!! ITS ALIVE!!  Maybe there was no NullPointersEx, because it works until i kill process. Android was making something like default, but when apps closing, default cleared. String data. and data nowbody know what inside. ))