# SharedPreferences in Android not getting recently updated values across multiple running processes

Tags: android, multiprocessing, android-sharedpreferences

Description:
I have two apps App1 and App2. I am using App1 to store some key value pair in SharedPreferences. I am accessing the same key value in App2.

I launch app1. Create a key with value abc. Now I keep app1 in background and launch App2 and I change the key value to def.

When I launch app1 from background to foreground and access the key value. Value retrieved is abc instead of updated value def. If I kill App2 from background and relaunch it then only updated value is getting reflected

Comment: Have you tried to call `getSharedPreferences()` with `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE`? Or `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` (deprecated in API 23) ?

Comment: Yes I tried this. It works if the mode is mode_multi_process. But my requirement is to use mode_private

Comment: With `MODE_PRIVATE` only applications with the same user ID can access the Shared Preferences. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354035/two-android-applications-with-the-same-user-id

Comment: Yes these two apps have same shared user id in manifest

Comment: Are you saving data with `apply` or `commit`?

Comment: Tried with both but no luck

Comment: Are you trying to access the value of the SharedPreference in `onCreate`? If yes, try in `onResume`.

Comment: Accessing in onResume itself

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_MULTI_PROCESS Here it says that `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` was the standard behavior in Android 2.3. That's why it worked with API 8. If you don't want to change the mode maybe you should use a content provider: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: Thanks. Yes m researching on using content provider in place of SharedPreferences for my requirement

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SharedPreferences` has never supported multiple processes, let alone multiple apps. [The documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) explicitly states:

> *Note: This class does not support use across multiple processes.*

Comment: But this issue doesn't come if minsdk is set to 8 in app1. It only occurs when min sdk is greater than 8. How is this issue related to min sdk

Comment: @Shivanisrivastava: `minSdkVersion` has no runtime impact. It merely controls where your app can be installed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710076/cannot-share-sharedpreferences-between-activity-and-remote-service-android-bug

Comment: The above link mention similar issue

Comment: @Shivanisrivastava: `minSdkVersion` is not mentioned on that page, as you can tell by searching that page for `minSdkVersion`.

Comment: But it It is happening in my case.

Comment: @Shivanisrivastava: Since Google has indicated that `SharedPreferences` do not work across multiple processes, perhaps you should not use `SharedPreferences` across multiple processes.

Comment: Yes will search for other possible solutions. But still if this issue could be resolved using SharedPreferences itself that would have been great

Answer (score 0):

The value doesn't get updated as the SharedPreferences doesn't recognize data change across multiple processes.

Comment: But this issue doesn't occur if the min sdk is set to 8 in manifest of app1.

Comment: Are you sure with it? The Shared Preferences came in API Level 1 and this isn't mentioned in docs as well.

Comment: Yes there is no documentation related to this. But I am facing this issue. Not sure about the relation of SharedPreferences with min sdk. It works properly fine if I getsharedpreferences in multi_mode processes. But I want to use mode_private

Answer (score 0):

The shared preferences of an app are stored in a separate file within the app's internal storage which no other apps can access. The shared preferences of two different apps are located in two different locations and are independent of each other.

So the shared preferences of an app cannot be accessed by any other apps and change in the shared preferences of an app is not reflected in any other apps.

Comment: It can be accessed if both of these apps have the same shared user id in manifest

Answer (score 0):

When process reads the data from the SharedPreferences, it copies the values (data) and puts those data inside it's process inside the cache. It does this because reading/writing from disk is too slow. Generally, System creates cache process for Android Components. Now, your data from the SharedPreferences is stored in the component's cache process. Cache process has it's own memory space. Until the component is using the memory, it locks (critical section) in order to prevent other can't access that memory. The cache process should be killed so that other processes (or components) can now be able to access it. This is why when you relaunch you see the update.

**Critical Section:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section

**Different Processes:** https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle.html

In thread-level, you use the keyword `volatile`, so that you see the one thread updated data from second thread. But SharedPreferences can't be volatile because it is persistent storage.

That's why they explicitly stated **SharedPreferences doesn't support on multiple processes**

Comment: I don't know yet. I don't think it is possible. Because when a process goes in critical section it locks its memory space. After it gets killed it flushes that data to SharedPreferences. Now, another process can get the updated value. I am also researching on it, will let you know if I know...

Answer (score 0):

Sharedpreferences are not process safe as per their documentation. I ran into a similar problem. I was using a value from sharedpreferences within an activity and then in a service with another process. The same value was behaving like two different values.

Well i used this [lib](https://github.com/grandcentrix/tray) to solve this problem. Its basically the same approach and syntax and its process safe.

Answer (score 0):

`SharedPreferences` has never supported multiple processes, let alone multiple apps. The documentation explicitly states:

> Note: This class does not support use across multiple processes.

`SharedPreferences` had to be replaced with content provider in my case.